# How do you assign a short name to a variable in the netCDF4 module for python?

Tags: python, variables, netcdf

I'm making a netCDF file using code along the lines of:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
outfile = Dataset('output.nc', 'w', format = 'NETCDF4')
level = outfile.createDimension('level', 1)
time = outfile.createDimension('t', None)
lats = outfile.createDimension('latitude', 141)
lons = outfile.createDimension('longitude', 121)

precips = outfile.createVariable('Precipitation', 'f4',('t','level','latitude','longitude'))
times = outfile.createVariable('t','f8',('t',))
levels = outfile.createVariable('level','i4',('level',))
latitudes = outfile.createVariable('latitude','f4',('latitude',))
longitudes = outfile.createVariable('longitude','f4',('longitude',))
latitudes.units = "degrees east"
longitudes.units = "degrees north"
levels.units = "surface" 
precips.units = "mm/day"
times.calendar = "gregorian"
```

That all works fine (once you fill the variables with data and call `outfile.close()`), but how do you assign a short name to a variable? I would expect something along the lines of:

```
precips.shortFieldName = "prec"
```

But, having tried a number of variations on that, and scanned the docs, and rifled through the source code, I'm no closer to a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me: afterwards `print precips.shortFieldName` yields `u'prec'`.  What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the `setattr`?  `setattr(precips, 'shortFieldName', 'prec')`

Answer (score 0):

`prec=precips`
^^Then there are pointers on this not two objects 
=> 2 names which are both usable